# How to replace characters in a fixed length string?

Tags: java

I'd like to replace the content of a string between specific positions with a fixed characters.

Is there any common library (apache, guava) that provides a class similar to the following pseudocode?

`string.replaceBetween(10, 20, "*");`

If not, how could I best achieve this with regards to performance?

Comment: Use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: `String s2 = new StringBuilder(string).replace(10, 21, "*").toString();` should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about following way. You can use [replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace%28int,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29) in `StringBuilder`.

```
String str = "hi, how are you?";
String alterStr=new StringBuilder(str).replace(4,6,"*").toString();
System.out.println(alterStr);
```

Comment: This one. `StringBuffer` is `synchronized`.

Comment: I'm just saying that your answer is preferable to the other answer. (+1)

Comment: @BoristheSpider - You might have commented on the other answer :P

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple implement,

```
 public static String replace(String old  ,int begin, int end ,char oldChar ,char newChar ){
    if (oldChar != newChar) {
    char array[] = old.toCharArray();
    for(int i = begin;i<end;i++){
        if(old.charAt(i)==oldChar){
            array[i] = newChar;
        }
    }

    return new String(array);
    }
    return old;
}
```

it creates a new char array ,then updates each item in the array if needed.
The sad thing is ,it copies the char array again when building a new String.
But ,at least,the local array will be cleaned by GC.I think this is good enough,since the origin code of JDK1.6 String replace(char oldChar,char newChar) also creates
a local array as below,

```
public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar) {
if (oldChar != newChar) {
    int len = count;
    int i = -1;
    char[] val = value; /* avoid getfield opcode */
    int off = offset;   /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while (++i < len) {
    if (val[off + i] == oldChar) {
        break;
    }
    }
    if (i < len) {
    char buf[] = new char[len];
    for (int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++) {
        buf[j] = val[off+j];
    }
    while (i < len) {
        char c = val[off + i];
        buf[i] = (c == oldChar) ? newChar : c;
        i++;
    }
    return new String(0, len, buf);
    }
}
return this;
}
```

If you read the code in StringBuffer ,you can see a lot arrayCopy,so I think the
performance is not good.